# Url is returned with 404 error, but content exists

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, sitemap

So, I would like to get url "http://example.com/sitemap.xml". Content(xml) was returned and shown in browser. But in firebug I saw that status code of this url - 404. So, when I had posted this url to google webmaster they said "General HTTP error: 404 not found".

I can not understand how it could happen - In browser I see a valid xml, but this url return 404 error.

Server settings?

p.s. sitemap.xml is not a file. Content is generating using php.

Comment: How does `sitemap.xml` run PHP? Url rewriting or is `xml` being ran through PHP interpreter?

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the code in your php. For all we know you start your code with `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");`, and then echo some content :)

Comment: sitemap.xml run thought Url rewriting - each url goes to index.php and parse in php. And I can not show relevant part of the code, 'cause there are a lot of files and includes. Now I'm trying to find header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); but can not yet.

Comment: If you do not have the the above mentioned 404 header line in your code (the script is a 404 handler so 404 is assumed/set by server by default), then specify `200` code explicitly on the very top of your code: `header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK", true);`

Comment: What happens if you call sitemap.xml in your browser?

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you, 'header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK", true);' works on localhost, but doesn't work on production server. I suggest the problem happens on server.

Comment: @Pekka I receive a valid xml.

Comment: You could also try `header("Content-type: text/xml");` in your PHP file, but I do not assume that to be the problem.

Comment: What header do you get when you open it in your browser? Can you give a live URL for us to try out?

Comment: @Pekka http://blunch.com.ua/sitemap.xml

Comment: @lexa: can you show your `.htaccess` -- situation may be improved by adding/changing rewrite rule or altering some other setting.

Comment: It's indeed sending a 404. The reason why it doesn't work on the server might be because contradicting headers are treated differently. I think you *must* have a 404 header somewhere in the code

Comment: @Pekka I had a 404 on localhost and when I added header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); it starts working, but on production nothing changes :( I suppose there are server settings there.  I do - header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); echo $oXmlDoc->saveXML(); exit; So if I had a header-404 I would overwrite it.

Comment: Strange. Do you have access to the server logs to see whether the 404 gets triggered on server side after all?

Comment: I would suggest to have explicit rewrite rule for sitemap.xml -- to be redirected to index.php (preferably to a dedicated script (e.g. `sitemap.php`) to exclude whatever complications index.php may unintentionally introduce).

Comment: @LazyOne Exectly!!!! I've just solved this problem like you said. Thank you, guys!

Comment: @lexa: I will post the solution as an answer then so you can accept it and for the other people to find the solution easier. Thnx.

Answer (score 4):

Based on our conversation in question's comments:

1) Specify `200` code explicitly on the very top of your code: `header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK", true);`

2) Based on your .htaccess I think that the request for sitemap.xml is not handled directly to index.php, instead it goes via 404 handler first. I would suggest to have explicit rewrite rule for sitemap.xml to be redirected to index.php (preferably to a dedicated script (e.g. `sitemap.php`) to exclude whatever complications index.php may unintentionally introduce).